# $_FILES data is always null

Tags: php, post, file-upload, file

I'm trying to post a PNG image. Here is my code.

```
<form action="http://killprashanth.res.cmu.edu/index.php/main/post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> 
<div class="hidden"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="" /> 
 <input type="hidden" name="thread" value="" /> 
</div>
<label for="text">Message text:</label>
<textarea name="text" cols="90" rows="12" ></textarea><br>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td style="width: 40%;">
   <label for="file">Image (optional):</label>
   <input type="file" name="file" value=""  />
  </td>
  <td style="width: 60%;">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" onclick="reload()" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and

```
public function post()
{
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], '/uploads'.$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        $data = array(
                'userid' => $_POST['userid'],
                'thread' => $_POST['thread'],
                'text' => $_POST['text'],
                'image' => $_FILES["file"]["name"]
        );

        $this->db->insert('messages', $data);
}
```

In my database, everything works except image (a varchar) is always NULL.

Comment: Does the file upload to your uploads directory?

Comment: have you checked the whole array: print_r($_FILES)?

Comment: Don't use user-supplied filenames to write to your filesystem. Here you've got a nasty directory-traversal security hole, but there are plenty of other problems to go round. Store files under automatically-generated known-good names like `uploadid-17236478.png`.

Comment: Nope, not in the uploads directory at all. I ran print_r, but nothing showed up in the browser (is that how it's supposed to work?). Thanks, yeah, I originally had it designed to use messageid.bbq as the file name, but I mucked around with it in attempts to just get the thing working.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing:

```
onclick="reload()"
```

See if it works now.  This may be breaking the file upload (it runs "reload" before the form is submitted).

If you want to reload the page instead of actually GOING to the posted page, you may want to look into POSTing through AJAX.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I should have mentioned that the function doesn't actually do anything at the moment. I'll try that though; thanks.

Comment: Try mimicking the sample code on the php page:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php
Maybe the file is throwing an error?  This is very weird for it not to be working.  I will set it up on my computer and test your code.  Give me a couple minutes...